# How would I input this truth table into Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha

Tags: inputfield, logic

[image: Logic Circuit]

I am unsure how to put the negations after a gate or before a gate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

[image]

Assuming I have not made an error (apologies if I have), this reduces to False for all inputs.

```
x1 = Nand[a, b];
x2 = Or[b, c];
x3 = And[x1, And[x1, Not[x2]]];
x4 = Nor[x1, x3];
x5 = And[x3, x4];
```

The truth table:

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{a, b, c, x5}, {a, b, c}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {a, b, c, x5}}]
```

[image]

and `BooleanMinimize[x5]` yields `False`

Comment: Great I was confused how to enter the negation on one input of the AND gate.